# Access global class name hidden by local name

Tags: c#

Example:

```
namespace MyApp.NET
{
    class Class1
    {
      public enum Types : byte = {t1, t2, t3};
      public Types m_type = t1;
    }

    class Class2
    {
      Class1 [] m_data = new Class1 [100];
      public Class1 Class1 (int i) { return m_data [i]; }
      void Method2 (Class1 c)
      {
         if (c.m_type == Class1.Types.t1) {}
      }
    }

    class MyApp
    {
    }
}
```

Class1.Types.t1 isn't visible because of the method Class2.Class1. Is there a way to qualify Class1.Types.t1 so that it is accessible in the context outlined above? The issue is complicated by the namespace having the same partial name as another class.

Comment: you mean myNameSpace.Class1.Types.t1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

global::MyApp.Net.Class1.Types.t1

Comment: cdhowies answer has led me on the right track, and I have subsequently found this even in some code of my project the IDE had created automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by namespace: `myNameSpace.Class1.Types.t1`.  If these types were not in a namespace, then you could qualify it by forcing global scope: `global::Class1.Types.t1`.

Comment: I tried that, but the actual namespace name is "DLE.NET", and using "DLE.NET.Class1" yielded an error, because I also have a global class "DLE", so MSVC 2010 mistakes "DLE.NET" for a member of class "DLE". I probably need to rename my namespace ...

Comment: I know now how to do it if there is a class in the namespace with the same name as the namespace: I need to prefix the namespace name with "global::".

Answer (score 0):

> `myNameSpace.Class1.Types.t1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c.m_type == myNameSpace.Class1.Types.t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just start qualifying as below:

```
if (c.m_type == NET.Class1.Types.t1) {}
```

Alternatively, if you add an alias for the `Class1` class:

```
namespace MyApp.NET
{
    using C1 = Class1;
    ...
}
```

your `if` statement can then become:

```
if (c.m_type == C1.Types.t1) {}
```

This will let you do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but imo things like that obscure the code.

Comment: @karx11erx: I've just noticed I had used an inner namespace in my test code when trying this out, so I've added a much simpler solution in my edited answer.